# Why is source code included in the APK file?

Tags: java, android

In an android APK file which has been compiled for shipping, it is possible to extract the source code from it (I realize it is slightly changed code). But why is this possible? Why does it would it include the source code in the files? Doesn't this make copying, hacking, remaking, etc much easier and just hurt developers in the end? I am not asking why it is easy to decompile an APK file. I'm wondering why the APK file includes the source code. If I'm mistaken and the APK file is just being decoded then correct me, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're mistaken.  It doesn't include the source, the compiled Java bytecode is being reconstructed into code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @LouisWasserman